# Js price range slider working only in first section

Tags: javascript, html, css

price range slider:
[image: img]
I have used the price range slider in my HTML page, but i need to add this price range slider in three different sections on same HTML page.
but only the first section price slider is working , other two sliders are not working.
here is my code

```js
const rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input"),
  priceInput = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input input"),
  range = document.querySelector(".slider .progress1");

let priceGap = 1000;

priceInput.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("input", e => {
    let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput[0].value),
      maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput[1].value);

    if ((maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap) && maxPrice <= rangeInput[1].max) {
      if (e.target.className === "input-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = minPrice;
        range.style.left = ((minPrice / rangeInput[0].max) * 100) + "%";
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = maxPrice;
        range.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
      }
    }
  });
});

rangeInput.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener("input", e => {
    let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput[0].value),
      maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput[1].value);

    if ((maxVal - minVal) < priceGap) {
      if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = maxVal - priceGap
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
      }
    } else {
      priceInput[0].value = minVal;
      priceInput[1].value = maxVal;
      range.style.left = ((minVal / rangeInput[0].max) * 100) + "%";
      range.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="price-input">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="number" class="input-min" value="1000">
    <div class="separator">-</div>
    <input type="number" class="input-max" value="100000">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="progress1"></div>
</div>
<div class="range-input">
  <input type="range" class="range-min" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" step="100">
  <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="100000" value="100000" step="100">
</div>



//second slider
<div class="price-input">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="number" class="input-min" value="1000">
    <div class="separator">-</div>
    <input type="number" class="input-max" value="100000">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="progress1"></div>
</div>
<div class="range-input">
  <input type="range" class="range-min" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" step="100">
  <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="100000" value="100000" step="100">
</div>
```

i am trying to activate all price slider with only  one javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is only for slider1, so I update your code as below

```
<div class="slider1-wrapper">
    <div class="price-input">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="number" class="input-min" value="1000">
            <div class="separator">-</div>
            <input type="number" class="input-max" value="100000">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="progress1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range-input">
        <input type="range" class="range-min" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" step="100">
        <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="100000" value="100000" step="100">
    </div>

    </div>
</div>



<div class="slider2-wrapper">
    <div class="price-input">

        <div class="field">
            <input type="number" class="input-min" value="1000">
            <div class="separator">-</div>
            <input type="number" class="input-max" value="100000">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="progress1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="range-input">
        <input type="range" class="range-min" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" step="100">
        <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="100000" value="100000" step="100">
    </div>

    </div>
</div>


<script>
    let priceGap = 1000;

    //js for slider1
    const rangeInput1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider1-wrapper .range-input input"),
        priceInput1 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider1-wrapper .price-input input"),

        range1 = document.querySelector(".slider1-wrapper .slider .progress1");    

    priceInput1.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput1[0].value),
                maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput1[1].value);

            if ((maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap) && maxPrice <= rangeInput1[1].max) {
                if (e.target.className === "input-min") {
                    rangeInput1[0].value = minPrice;
                    range1.style.left = ((minPrice / rangeInput1[0].max) * 100) + "%";
                } else {
                    rangeInput1[1].value = maxPrice;
                    range1.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput1[1].max) * 100 + "%";
                }
            }
        });
    });

    rangeInput1.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput1[0].value),
                maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput1[1].value);

            if ((maxVal - minVal) < priceGap) {
                if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
                    rangeInput1[0].value = maxVal - priceGap
                } else {
                    rangeInput1[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
                }
            } else {
                priceInput1[0].value = minVal;
                priceInput1[1].value = maxVal;
                range1.style.left = ((minVal / rangeInput1[0].max) * 100) + "%";
                range1.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput1[1].max) * 100 + "%";
            }
        });
    });



   //js for slider2

    const rangeInput2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider2-wrapper .range-input input"),
        priceInput2 = document.querySelectorAll(".slider2-wrapper .price-input input"),

        range2 = document.querySelector(".slider2-wrapper .slider .progress1");
          
    priceInput2.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput1[0].value),
                maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput1[1].value);

            if ((maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap) && maxPrice <= rangeInput2[1].max) {
                if (e.target.className === "input-min") {
                    rangeInput2[0].value = minPrice;
                    range2.style.left = ((minPrice / rangeInput2[0].max) * 100) + "%";
                } else {
                    rangeInput2[1].value = maxPrice;
                    range2.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput2[1].max) * 100 + "%";
                }
            }
        });
    });

    rangeInput2.forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("input", e => {
            let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput2[0].value),
                maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput2[1].value);

            if ((maxVal - minVal) < priceGap) {
                if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
                    rangeInput2[0].value = maxVal - priceGap
                } else {
                    rangeInput2[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
                }
            } else {
                priceInput2[0].value = minVal;
                priceInput2[1].value = maxVal;
                range2.style.left = ((minVal / rangeInput2[0].max) * 100) + "%";
                range2.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput2[1].max) * 100 + "%";
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Pranil, did you check my solution?